# Send a SecureString to a remote server - Is this possible?

Tags: string, security, client

I'm currently working on a Client-Server type Chat Room. I'll get straight to the issue: I'm dealing with user passwords via SecureString and I'm having trouble sending that information to my server application (via System.Net.Sockets). I've been somewhat successful with handling the SecureString with the "Marshal" class, but sending it from one client to it's server seems almost impossible based on how its handled. I've been searching on the internet for a couple of days now looking if its even possible to send a SecureString over the wire without "exposing" it in plain text.

Essentially, all I'm questioning is if there is a way to get some type of information from a SecureString, that can be converted into a byte[] and can be understood enough to retrieve the password within.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you have a key on the client side, you have the possibility for the user, themselves, to get at this key.  Then, if they can intercept another user's traffic, you have a problem since they can use this key to decrypt whatever you're sending to the server.

So, you could create a separate key for each client.  But now you have a bunch of annoying overhead looking up the decryption keys on the server.

Why not just use https?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I've been considering https actually - Just fairly unfamiliar with it. Unless I'm understanding encryption entirely wrong, one would have to figure out the how the key is used (algorithmically). It would be a much tougher task than simply snooping at a plain text password. But I'll certainly look into https - My professor suggested looking into SecureString, thats why I had asked about SecureString specifically. Is https fairly easy to implement?

Comment: Generally quite easy, yes.... it sounds like a web app, in which case you'd simply install a secure certificate in your server (IIS?) and configure it to allow access to your app from https://whatever.com instead of http://whatever.com.  Here's a Google search to help you on your way:  http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=install+secure+certificate+iis&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8.   That being said, if this is homework you may not be able to use it, if (s)he specifically wants you to solve a problem on your own which the use of HTTPS could easily circumvent.

Comment: Its a WPF application that's communicating with a web service via http. I've been googling already, was just asking your opinion on the matter. And this is a final project for college graduation. I've already completed it - just trying to add some extra "features" like security. I had asked my professor's advice that's all - he does not care one way or the other. Thank you for your help! Much appreciated.